# Is there a way to set the color of the spacing in a table

Tags: html, html-table

Is there a way to set the color of the spacing in a table? For example I want a color for the row that contains the th elements and a different color for the row that contains td elements.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "spacing"? The space in between columns?

Comment: Could be just different `background-color` for `th` and `td`

Comment: by spacing i mean the space that is set by the cellspacing attribute

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `first-child` selector to have the first row colored with different color:

```css
tr { background-color: lime; }
tr:first-child { background-color: yellow; }
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/JACxc/